# vs2010: Gradient background in a windows application

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am working on visual studios 2010 and c++. I am trying to change the background color of my basic windows app i want to put gradient colors to it like how `skype` and other programs do is it possible? As far as my guess is that i have to add gradient brush on the `WNDCLASSEX.hbrBackground` so far i could only find this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371488%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd799414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But i could not make it work as a whole background, i am just making guesses as i am completely lost and an example code or description on how to achieve this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  you want to support versions prior to Vista, you needed to handle WM_ERASEBKGND  message in your window proc and do the whole painting of the background yourself.  Read about GDI or GDI+  at msdn on how to do it.

Comment: I advise against using WM_ERASEBKGND and do all drawing in WM_PAINT, draw all into a memory DC and finally BitBlt that to the window DC -- to eliminate flicker issues.